# Docker Build Fails at "locate package python-pydot"

Tags: python, windows, docker

[Error Image]
I am using Windows 10 and try to build a Dockerfile using wsl 2. However, I am facing this error:

g@Lucy:/mnt/c/Users/rma$ cd bsgen

g@Lucy:/mnt/c/Users/rma/bsgen$ docker build -t myimage1:1.0 .

[+] Building 7.0s (7/19)
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.1s

=> => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                                                                0.1s

=> [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.1s

=> => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s

=> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:8                                                       3.7s

=> [ 1/16] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:8@sha256:c498405e558f67cea05d04d63c5daf930d0c1fbbf451c8f04f0e2321d740c  0.0s

=> => resolve docker.io/library/openjdk:8@sha256:c498405e558f67cea05d04d63c5daf930d0c1fbbf451c8f04f0e2321d740cb8  0.0s

=> CACHED [ 2/16] RUN apt-get update                                                                              0.0s

=> CACHED [ 3/16] RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip                                                      0.0s

> [ 4/16] RUN apt-get -y install python3-pydot python-pydot python-pydot-ng graphviz:

> #7 1.094 Reading package lists...

> #7 2.076 Building dependency tree...

> #7 2.293 Reading state information...

> #7 2.501 E: Unable to locate package python-pydot

> #7 2.501 E: Unable to locate package python-pydot-ng

---

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install python3-pydot python-pydot python-pydot-ng graphviz]: exit code: 100

Can anyone help with it? I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Thank you so much in advance!

I've tried to do on Windows Terminal and faced the same error. I did install the python-pydot, pynot--ng, and graphviz but it wouldn't help me to solve this issue.

I am really new to everything, just installed Docker and WSL.. So it would be great if you can give de some guidance in detail, please.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you building an Ubuntu 18.04 based Docker image in Ubuntu 18.04 running using WSL2? Please edit your post to include the Dockerfile - at least from the start of the file to the RUN instruction that is failing - so that folks can better understand the issue.

Comment: Hello, I am just trying to build Dockerfile from Github(https://github.com/lgbanuelos/bsgen). I am not sure whether this image is based Ubuntu 18.04.... Is there any way to find out? or other solutions?

Comment: You can check the details of their base image (`FROM base_image` at the start of this Dockerfile is `FROM openjdk:8`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are working with python3, so you should install the python3 versions of `pydot` and `pydot-ng`: the already requested `python3-pydot` and the `python3-pydot-ng` package.

Change the Dockerfile contents to the following:

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

RUN apt-get -y install python3-pydot python3-pydot-ng graphviz
RUN apt-get -y install python3-tk
RUN apt-get -y install zip unzip
RUN apt-get -y install gcc gfortran python-dev libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev cython
RUN apt-get -y install g++ libboost-all-dev libncurses5-dev wget
RUN apt-get -y install libtool flex bison pkg-config g++ libssl-dev automake
RUN apt-get -y install libjemalloc-dev libboost-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-regex-dev python3-dev autoconf flex bison cmake
RUN apt-get -y install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libfreetype6-dev libsuitesparse-dev
RUN pip3 install -U wheel six pytest
RUN pip3 install backcall==0.2.0 colorama==0.4.4 cycler==0.10.0 decorator==5.0.7 deprecation==2.1.0 graphviz==0.16 intervaltree==3.1.0 ipython==7.22.0 ipython-genutils==0.2.0 jedi==0.18.0 jinja2==3.0.0a1 joblib==1.0.1 jsonpickle==2.0.0 kiwisolver==1.3.1 lxml==4.6.3 MarkupSafe==2.0.0rc1 matplotlib==3.4.1 mpmath==1.2.1 networkx==2.5.1 numpy==1.20.2 packaging==20.9 pandas==1.2.4 parso==0.8.2 pickleshare==0.7.5 pillow==8.2.0 prompt-toolkit==3.0.18 pulp==2.1 pydotplus==2.0.2 pygments==2.8.1 pyparsing==3.0.0b2 python-dateutil==2.8.1 pytz==2021.1 pyvis==0.1.9 scikit-learn==0.24.1 scipy==1.6.2 setuptools==56.0.0 six==1.15.0 sortedcontainers==2.3.0 stringdist==1.0.9 sympy==1.8 threadpoolctl==2.1.0 tqdm==4.60.0 traitlets==5.0.5 wcwidth==0.2.5
RUN pip3 install pm4py
RUN pip3 install notebook ipywidgets

WORKDIR /home/lgarcia
```